# Single pixel array value in time over image sequence using ImageJ

Tags: imagej

What I'd like to do is simple enough, however, I couldn't find out how. I use ImageJ to import sequence of images, and I want to export the values of pixel(0,0) at every frame in the sequence. If anyone knows a simple way to achieve it, it would be great.

Comment: In which way do you want to export the data? The easiest would be to just crop the stack to the selection of the desired pixel.

Comment: Anyway in which I can save it in a normal txt document. I'll admit that "crop the stack to the selection of the desired pixel" Doesn't tell me much. If you can give a bit more details it would be great.

Comment: Create a point-selection of the pixel in question (here: 0,0). Then go to "Image >> Crop". The result is a stack consisting of the values at the selected pixel. Please also see the Answer below.

Comment: In fact you need to make a single pixel square area selection because a point-selection doesn't work for subsequent cropping.

Comment: The easiest way to create a single pixel selection is by first setting a point selection and then using "Edit >> Selection >> To Bounding Box". Now go to "Image >> Crop" and then to "Image >> Stacks >> Reslice" where you check "Rotate 90 degrees" and "Avoid interpolation" (leave everything else as is). Finally go to "Image >> Transform >> Image to Results".

Answer (score 1):

Below is an ImageJ demo-macro that generates a stack of gray-value slices and plots the values at pixel (0,0) as a function of the slice position:

```
newImage("test","8-bit noise",256,256,32);
n=nSlices;
a=newArray(n);
for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
   setSlice(i);
   a[i]=getValue(0,0);
}
Plot.create("Values at the origin", "Slice", "calibrated Value",a);
Plot.setLimits(1,NaN,NaN,NaN);
exit();
```

If you prefer as output a tab-delimited string, you may consider:

```
newImage("test","8-bit noise",256,256,32);
str="";
for ( i=1; i<=nSlices; i++ ) {
   setSlice(i);
   str+=toString(getValue(0,0))+"\t";
}
print(str);
exit();
```

Based on my initial suggestion, the following demo-macro gives you a table that can be saved in CSV-format (comma separated values).

```
newImage("test","8-bit noise",256,256,32);
makeRectangle(0,0,1,1);
run("Duplicate...","title=test-pixel duplicate");
run("Reslice [/]...","output=1.000 start=Top rotate avoid");
run("Image to Results");
close(); close();
exit();
```

Paste the above macro code to an empty macro window (Plugins >> New >> Macro) and run it.

Comment: Really thank you for your hard work and reply. Unfortunately I never used macros in imagej. I will definitly give it a go but it might take a while.

Comment: Look at my last comment that explains how you can ahieve the same as what the last macro does but with manual menu-operations.